# Pass variables to template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templating

im using NodeJS/Expressjs and I have this route:

```
router.post({

   var value = req.body.value;
   //I NEED TO DO SOMETHING LIKE
   var file = '../test/test.js';
   file.render(value);

});
```

and /test/test.js looks like

```
var myVar = {value1};
var someStruct = {key: {value2}}
function Test(){
  var info = {value3};
}
```

Which is the good way to do this?
Can I use some templating system?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the EJS templating system. Does what you are asking.

```
// server.js
// load the things we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// pass and object/string into the render function as the second arg.
app.post('/your-url', function(req, res) {
    let data = {
        object: 'string'
    };
    res.render('pages/index', data);
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

Comment: Yes I'm using ejs but I want to save the rendered code to a javascript disk file.